# Rails: passing variable to jQuery

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

This should be simple but I am stuck. I am trying to pass a value from **erb** to **jQuery** in a Rails app. There are two popups. One on page load and another on a button click. Both return **undefined**.

Also, is there a simpler form of the **content_tag** I can use for passing variables?

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= content_tag "div", id: "batch_status", data: {batch_status: @batch.status} do %><% end %>
```

**rendered page html source**

```
<div data-batch-status="completed" id="batch_status"></div>
```

**batches.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
  alert $('#batch_status').data('batch_status')

  $("#apply_btn").on "click", ->
    alert $('#batch_status').data('batch_status')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= content_tag "div", id: "batch_status", 'data-batch_status' => @batch.status do %><% end %>
```